# Diagnose slow link

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a project (x64) which is taking a long time to link.

I set the link to VERBOSE then watched assorted text flash by, then it says...

```
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>
1>  Finished pass 1
1>
1>  Generating code
```

This is where it remains for up a to a minute. I am wondering, could it be taking its time because its trying some fancy optimisation... or could it be that I have a large amount of static data? Are there any linker settings that may help speed things up?

BTW, I have a i7 PC with 16GB RAM and and the compiler and project are all stored on a Solid State Drive.

**Edit:** it links 10x faster with a debug build, but I need to work with the release version because otherwise the program runs too slowly.

**Edit:** Below you can see the optimisation settings dialog from the (fast) debug configuration. The selections for enable COMDAT folding, function order and link time code generation are all blank... I have no idea what "blank" means. I can't set enable COMDAT folding, function order and link time code generation to blank in the release configuration, the dropdown menu's for each of them does not have blank as an option and I don't know what to set them to in order to give the linker the least amount of work to do.

[image]

**Edit:** There doesn't seem to be a way to disable link time code generation! It's not an option when in the release configuration!

Comment: You could try to disable LTO. But waiting 10x longer to link a Release build vs. a Debug build sounds normal.

Comment: I would like to, but it is not obvious what to select to achieve this.

Comment: Under Linker / General, set Show Progress to "Verbose", and see if that gives you clues about what in particular is taking extra long.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to disabling link-time optimization, you might also want to try disabling whole-program optimization (in options at 'C/C++ -> Optimization -> Whole Program Optimization').

[image: Screenshot]

Some additional options from [the C++ team](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/speeding-up-the-incremental-developer-build-scenario/):

1. /incremental (linker)
2. /Zc:inline (compiler)
3. /debug:FASTLINK (linker)
4. /LTCG:incremental (linker)

Note that you can find all of the linker options in VS under 'Configuration Properties > Linker > All Options'. There you can search for e.g. 'Link Time Code Generation'.

Comment: I can't see "All Options" under  'Configuration Properties > Linker > .. all I see is general, input,manifest file,debugging,system,optimisation,embedded IDL, advanced and command line.

Comment: Seems your version of VS is slightly different to mine :-(